# How to fetch set of data using ID in hibernate if we have composite primary key?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-mapping

I have Entities (Student,StudentSkills, StudentEmpSkills)

Student.java

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "Student", catalog = "dbs")
 public class Student implements java.io.Serializable {

 private int id;
 ...
 ...

 private Set<StudentSkills> studentSkills= new HashSet<StudentSkills>(0);
 private Set<StudentEmpSkills> studentEmpSkills= new HashSet<StudentEmpSkills>(0);


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "Student")
public Set<StudentSkills> getStudentSkills() {
    return this.studentEmpSkills;
}

public void setStudentSkills(
        Set<StudentSkills> studentSkills) {
    this.studentSkills = studentSkills;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "Student")
public Set<StudentEmpSkills> getStudentEmpSkills() {
    return this.StudentEmpSkills;
}

public void setStudentEmpSkills(
        Set<StudentEmpSkills> studentEmpSkills) {
    this.studentEmpSkills= studentEmpSkills;
}
}
```

in StudentEmpSkills.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "studentEmpSkills", catalog = "npdbs")
public class StudentEmpSkills implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private StudentEmpSkillsId id;
private Student Student ;

......


 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn(name = "studentID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
 public Student getStudent() {
    return student;
}
```

In the above we are getting the Set of StudentEmpSkils from Student by one to many and many to one relation.

as we are getting **Student** from **StudentEmpSkill**

In JoinColumn we are giving **studentID** column to fetch the abject.

Now I want to get StudentSkill object from StudentEmpSkills.

StudentSkills  -  (studentID* | skillID*) | skillname

StudentEmpSkills - (studentID* | skillID* | empID*) | empName

(..) - composit primary key

So I want to fetch StudentSkills from StudentEmpSkill

What I need to write in StudentEmpSkills  to fetch StudentSkill. because we have composit primary key in StudentSkill.

How to map the StudentSkill to StudentEmpSkills.

Can anyone please suggest?